# Unable to execute .sh file from docker container in Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, docker, sh

I am using Windows 10, and working on a Django Project with Docker.

If I run a python command from inside docker container, it runs perfectly.

```
E:\path>docker exec -it my_docker_container bash      
                                             
root@701z00f607ae:/app# python manage.py makemigrations authentication
No changes detected in app 'authentication'enter code here
```

But when I try to run same command using a .sh file, it gives different output.

```
root@701z00f607ae:/app# cat ./migration_script.sh 
python manage.py makemigrations authentication

root@701z00f607ae:/app# ./migration_script.sh 
'. installed app with label 'authentication
```

**Note:** Executing `./migration_script.sh` works perfectly on Linux based system.

Comment: Try replacing `./migration_script.sh` with `bash migration_script.sh` might be that it does not have +x flag enable for user.

Comment: @PranjalDoshi Unsuccessful. Still having the same output.

Comment: What is the error after changing to `bash migration_script.sh`? @SAIFAHMEDANIK